# Making a long Dataframe based on columns and row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So suppose I have a dataframe like:

```
    A   B 
0   1   1
1   2   4
2   3   9
```

I want to have one long dataframe where there are three columns row, col, value like:

```
    row col  value
0   0   A    1 
1   1   A    2 
2   2   A    3 
3   0   B    1
4   1   B    4 
5   2   B    9
```

Basically making a 2D array into 1D and remembering the row and column of each entry so the resulting dataframe would be of shape (n*m , 3).

How is this possible with Pandas? 
Actually the order of entries in the resulting dataframe isn't important for me.

Comment: `df.stack().reset_index()`

Answer (score 0):

use melt:

```
df = df.reset_index()
df.melt(id_vars=['index'], value_vars=['A','B'])
```

it should give you the thing you want. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Yeah it works for this example but I was looking for the general case and not specifying the [A, B] list

Comment: A.Fazeli: `df.reset_index().melt(id_vars=['index'])` works fine too. It takes `value_vars` as all columns not specified in `id_vars`